# Adding shortcode

Tags: shortcode

Hi I've a very simple question, I've installed a plugin which requires some code to be added to the Gallery shortcode.

To replace wordpress gallery with Zoom OpenSeadragon gallery you need to add openseadragon="true" to gallery shortcode. You can also use Media options to replace all galleries with Zoom OpenSeadragon gallery.

To show zoomable images, e.g. Deep Zoom images, you need to add paths of them to zoomimages attribute of shortcode, for example

```
[gallery openseadragon="true" zoomimages="/example.com/zoom/zoom1.dzi,/example.com/zoom/zoom2.dzi"]
```

I'm confused about what is required as I'm a shortcode noob. Do I simply add the line in the .php file where gallery shortcode is located?

Comment: Best bet is to inquire with the plugin author.  They likely offer some documentation or a support forum, FAQ.

Comment: nope that's all there is I'm afraid

Comment: From what I understand, you don't need to edit any php file, just throw the shortcode in your post/page content. What you need to "add" is the attribute(s) in the shortcode, as in the example you have here, this is to be done directly in your content, not in any php file.

Answer (score 1):

Short codes are designed to be used by people without needing to code or access php files.

Simply put that code in a post or page content.  (add new post, edit post, and new page, edit page, etc.  Save the post / page. and then the shortcode does it's "magic" of creating the gallery on whatever post or page you put your shortcode.  No need to access PHP files.

Comment: Or, if really needed (not suggested), use the do_shortcode function in template PHP files.